# How to fix a misconfiguration with Phusion Passenger and a VirtualHost directive?

Tags: apache, passenger, virtualhost, mod-rails, phusion

I have done this, can anyone tell me why my Rails application isn't loading?

```
hack ~ # cd /www ; rails mysite.com ; cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
hack sites-available # cat default
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias dev.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /www/htdocs/mysitecom
        ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /www/logs/mysite.com/error_combined_log 7862400"
        CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /www/logs/mysite.com/access_combined_log 7862400" combined
        ServerSignature email
        RailsBaseURI /
        <Directory /www/htdocs/mysite.com>
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


hack sites-available #
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You've initialized your app at /www/mysite.com but pointed your DocumentRoot at a different directory, /www/htdocs/mysitecom (and I'm assuming you meant `rails new mysite.com`).
2. DocumentRoot should point to your app's public dir.

Change DocumentRoot to /www/mysite.com/public or wherever your app's public folder actually lives.

Make sure passenger is enabled (and quit using root):

```
hack $ sudo a2enmod passenger
hack $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```